# Program runs perfectly the first time but wondering seg faults the second time when reading from a class from binary file?

Tags: c++, class, binaryfiles

The issue I am having is that the program runs great the first time but seg faults the second time. The one difference is the first time the binary file is created and the second time the data is appended to the binary file.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

//count of the number of car classes written to bin file
int num_of_cars_written;
// This will be the class written to binary
class Car{
    public:
    std::string model;
    int num_of_wheels;
    std::vector<std::string> list_of_features;
    Car(std::string model, int num_of_wheels){
        this->model = model;
        this->num_of_wheels = num_of_wheels;
    }
    Car(){
        this->model = "";
        this->num_of_wheels = 0;
    }
};

void write_to_binary_file(Car& car){
    std::fstream ofile("cars.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::app | std::ios::out);
    ofile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&car), sizeof(Car));
    ofile.close();
    ++num_of_cars_written;
}

std::vector<Car> read_bin_of_cars(std::string bin_file_path){
    std::vector<Car> car_list;
    std::fstream file(bin_file_path, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    int size_of_file = sizeof(file);
    int number_of_cars_read_so_far = 0;
    Car* car;
    while(!file.eof()){
        file.read (reinterpret_cast<char*>(car), sizeof(Car));
        car_list.push_back(*car);
        number_of_cars_read_so_far += size_of_file / num_of_cars_written;
        if(number_of_cars_read_so_far >= size_of_file) break;
    }
    file.close();
    return car_list;
}

int main(){
    Car car_one("mazda", 4);
    car_one.list_of_features.push_back("cup holder");
    car_one.list_of_features.push_back("gps");
    Car car_two("honda", 4);
    Car car_three("sazuki", 2);
    car_three.list_of_features.push_back("leather seat");
    write_to_binary_file(car_one);
    write_to_binary_file(car_two);
    write_to_binary_file(car_three);
    std::vector<Car> list = read_bin_of_cars("cars.bin");
    for(auto car : list){
        std::cout << "**************Car Object**************\n";
        std::cout << car.model << std::endl;
        std::cout << car.num_of_wheels << std::endl;
        for (auto feature : car.list_of_features) {
            std::cout << feature << std::endl;
        };
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here are the results from the first run

```
**************Car Object**************
mazda
4
cup holder
gps
**************Car Object**************
honda
4
**************Car Object**************
sazuki
2
leather seat
```

Here are the results from the second run

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped) (obviously)
```

EDIT:
this working on the first try is undefined behavior and shouldn't work. There are better ways listed in the comments to go about writing and reading to binary.

Comment: `ofile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&car), sizeof(Car));` You cannot serialize that class that way.

Comment: Do you have to serialize each data type in the class? why does this work the first time but not the second?

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Sometimes you get unlucky and it appears to work. Only to fail randomly later.

Comment: working the first time is undefined behavior? lol

Comment: Serializing types that are not POD types this way is undefined behavior. You can't serialize the vector or the string this way.

Comment: What is the best and easiest way to do this? write a serialize method for the class and serialize each member data?

Comment: Do you really need a binary file? This is an easier task if you use a text format.

Comment: fair point I'm doing this as a binary file to get more practice with them. there are easier ways but I wanted to try this

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182880/is-it-possible-to-simply-serialize-c-objects

Comment: Also related: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/198013/

Comment: And finally: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization

Comment: Thanks my man! this helped me a lot. I'll do it a better way

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues with this code. Summarizing few:

In `write_to_binary_file`:

`write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&car), sizeof(Car));` 
This is incorrect way of writing object to file. It will just write memory blog of object `car` and not necessarily will take care of members pointing to allocations outside of it (for example `string` or `vector` etc are not static arrays. They are most likely allocating memory outside of the object. Read about serialization and make use of it instead.

In `read_bin_of_cars`:

You are reading into pointer `car` without allocating memory to it. Again, even after you allocate memory, make sure you use serialization to read object from file.

Mind you `reinterpret_cast` is most dangerous. You should use it only when you know what you are doing. Casting object straight to character pointer is blunder.

There could be still other issues with the code. These are just I found at glance.